# laravel login does not work with cloudFront AWS and Certificate Manager

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-cloudfront

I have an application built on laravel. I needed to enable https on my system and I used the cloudfront and Certificate Manager.

I was able to configure everything! Except that the laravel authentication system stopped working. Apparently the session in laravel does not work with cloudFront (CDN).

The system shows no errors. It simply does not authenticate the user.

I suspect the reason is the cloudFront. Because the cloudFront is between the browser and the EC2 server. Anyone know if there is a laravel authentication problem with cloudFront and Certificate Manager

my system: https://loja2.softshop.com.br/login

credentials:

login: teste@sandbox.pagseguro.com.br
password: tim140

the laravel validation also does not show the error messages.

Comment: Did you configure the CloudFront Cache Behavior settings to forward any cookies?  By default, none will be forwarded and that would be a very likely explanation for the problem.

Comment: you're right! The problem was cookies! @Michael-sqlbot Thank you very much! I've worked hours trying to figure it out!!

Comment: What should be the cookie name to white list for laravel authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For web distributions, you can choose whether you want CloudFront to forward cookies to your origin and to cache separate versions of your objects based on cookie values in viewer requests.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Cookies.html

By default, no cookies are forwarded by CloudFront.  Since most web sites providing any kind of dynamic content use cookies for managing state and authentication, the default configuration usually needs to be modified for dynamic sites.

Note the caveats on the same page of the documentation -- you generally only want to forward cookies to your origin on requests where the origin actually needs to them, so you may want to create separate Cache Behaviors without cookies enabled for static resources, in order to maintain a reasonable cache hit ratio for those static resources.